# Android App Widget Vertical Swipe: accuweather.com

Tags: android, swipe, android-appwidget

On my Samsung S3 I have the accuweather.com **APP WIDGET** installed: when having multiple locations, you can get to the next location with **vertical swipe**. It also seams that they built in a crossfade animation for that action.

My questions are:
1) What kind of view is used?
2) If a listview is used: did they used a crossfade animation on fling?
3) If an adapterviewflipper is used: where can I find example source code (I didn't manage to convert the Android example 'StackWidgetExample')?

And of course, I would be very happy when receiving source code for a project like accuweather.com.

Comment: I have tried it with a StackView, but don't know how to customize it's children (size and position).

Answer (score 0):

Accuweather is no actually a android appwidget, its different. It has some support from the **TouchWitz Launcher** application. And its actually service based not broadcast receiver based.